# How to make cURL return false after if server doesn't respond after 2 second?

Tags: php, curl

I got this function, now sometimes when a site is down or loads for a long time it slows down my site's loading time.

Is there way I can make it just return false if a server doesn't respond within 2 seconds? As you can see I tried it with `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` but that didn't seem to do the trick.

```
function url_get_contents($url)
{
    if (!function_exists('curl_init'))
    {
        die('Exit: CURL is not installed or enabled!');
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to fetch that every time your site is viewed? It might be better to put it in a cron, and save the results, say every hour. You can then have a very long timeout, and your site doesn't need to wait around for the slow HTTP operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT - The number of seconds to wait while trying to
>   connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.
>
> CURLOPT_TIMEOUT - The maximum
>   number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.

use CURLOPT_TIMEOUT

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
```

---

Quoting from the [PHP cURL documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT: The number of seconds to wait while trying to
>   connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.
>   
>   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT    The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions
>   to execute.

Comment: In your short answer the time is supposed to be in seconds, not ms.

Comment: @KidDiamond My mistake. I was looking at `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS`.

Answer (score 0):

`CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` limits how long cURL will wait to establish a connection. The server still has to find content and send it, which normally takes longer.

cURL has another option, `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` which is a limit placed on the `curl_exec()` function. Think of it as a limit to the amount of time the function can take to return something. That sounds like what you're looking for:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I gues that you need to use curl_getinfo() function

see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

code will be like this

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```